# Integration of a $\int \frac{v^2+1}{v^3-v^2+v+1}\,dv$

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

While solving the DE $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{y^2-x^2}{y^2+x^2}$$ with the initial substitution $y=vx$ I got stuck in the integration of  :

$$\int \frac{v^2+1}{v^3-v^2+v+1}\,dv$$

I don't know how to proceed further. Kindly help.

Comment: Partial fractions will work but the numerical values you encounter will not be nice to work with.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The main difficulty is that your cubic doesn't have nice roots. Lets call them $v_r$, $v_c$ and $\bar{v_c}$ and let $v_c=a+bi$. I.e.

$$v^3-v^2+v+1=(v-v_r)(v-v_c)(v-\bar{v_c})$$

$$=(v-v_r)(v^2-2av+a^2+b^2)=(v-v_r)((v-a)^2+b^2)$$

Hence we can write:

$$\frac{v^2+1}{v^3-v^2+v+1}=\frac{A}{v-v_r}+\frac{Bv+C}{(v-a)^2+b^2}$$

$$v^2+1=A((v-a)^2+b^2)+(Bv+C)(v-v_r)$$

Next work out the coefficients $A$, $B$, and $C$.

If $v=v_r$ then:

$$v_r^2+1=A((v_r-a)^2+b^2)$$

$$A=\frac{v_r^2+1}{(v_r-a)^2+b^2}$$

If $v=0$ then:

$$1=A(a^2+b^2)+C(-v_r)$$

$$C=\frac{A(a^2+b^2)-1}{v_r}=\frac{2a+v_r(a^2+b^2-1)}{(v_r-a)^2+b^2}$$

Rearranging the equation for $B$ gives:

$$B=\frac{1+v^2-A((v-a)^2+b^2)-C(v-v_r)}{v(v-v_r)}$$

Subbing $A$ and $C$ back in and solving for $B$ gives (note the $v$ cancels out):

$$B=\frac{a^2+b^2-1-2av_r}{(v_r-a)^2+b^2}$$

You can then carry out the integral and finally sub back in the $A$, $B$ and $C$.

$$\int\frac{A}{v-v_r}+\frac{Bv+C}{(v_r-a)^2+b^2)}\ dv$$

$$=A\log{|v-v_r|}+\frac{aB+C}{b}\arctan\left(\frac{v-a}{b}\right)+\frac{B}{2}\log((v-a)^2+b^2)$$

Needless to say it doesn't end up pretty and doesn't have a nice closed form as you also need to substitute in the actual values for $v_r$, $a$ and $b$ which are:

$$v_r=\frac{(3\sqrt{33}-17)^{\frac23}+(3\sqrt{33}-17)^{\frac13}-2}{3(3\sqrt{33}-17)^{\frac13}}$$

$$a=\frac{-(3\sqrt{33}-17)^{\frac23}+2(3\sqrt{33}-17)^{\frac13}+2}{6(3\sqrt{33}-17)^{\frac13}}$$

$$b=\frac{\sqrt{3}(3\sqrt{33}-17)^{\frac13}+2\sqrt{3}}{6(3\sqrt{33}-17)^{\frac13}}$$

Of note [Wolframalpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Solve%20y%27%5Bx%5D%3D(y%5Bx%5D%5E2-x%5E2)%2F(y%5Bx%5D%5E2%2Bx%5E2)) also struggles to express this integral nicely.

Answer (score 2):

This came up last month and [my solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1719288/how-calculate-the-indefinite-integral-int-frac1x3x1dx/1719721#1719721) seemed a little cleaner. It's pretty much the same thing this time. Find a root of $v^3-v^2+v+1=0$, and the real one is
$$a=\frac13-\frac{2\sqrt2}3\sinh\left(\frac13\sinh^{-1}\left(\frac{17}{2\sqrt2}\right)\right)$$
Then partial fractions will go like
$$\frac{v^2+1}{v^3-v^2+v+1}=\frac A{v-a}+\frac{Bv+C}{v^2+(a-1)v+a^2-a+1}$$
Then we can use L'Hopital's rule to get $A$
$$A=\lim_{v\rightarrow a}\frac{(v-a)(v^2+1)}{v^3-v^2+v+1}=\frac{a^2+1}{3a^2-2a+1}$$
Then we need the arithmetic
$$(3a^2-2a+1)(2a^2-7a+3)=(6a-19)(a^3-a^2+a+1)+22$$
$$(a^2+1)(2a^2-7a+3)=(2a-5)(a^3-a^2+a+1)-2a^2-4a+8$$
So now we can say
$$\begin{align}\frac{a^2+1}{3a^2-2a+1} & =\frac{(a^2+1)(2a^2-7a+3)}{22}\\
 & =\frac{-a^2-2a+4}{11}\end{align}$$
And then we can get $B$ and $C$ by subtracting fractions and then dividing by $(v-a)$
$$\begin{align}\frac{v^2+1}{v^3-v^2+v+1} & =\frac {-a^2-2a+4}{11(v-a)}+\frac{(a^2+2a+7)v+5a^2-a+2}{11\left(v^2+(a-1)v+a^2-a+1\right)}\\
 & =\frac {-a^2-2a+4}{11(v-a)}+\frac{(a^2+2a+7)\left(v+\frac{a-1}2\right)+4a^2-3a+6}{11\left(v^2+(a-1)v+a^2-a+1\right)}\end{align}$$
So we can integrate to get
$$\begin{align}\int\frac{v^2+1}{v^3-v^2+v+1}dv= & \frac{-a^2-2a+4}{11}\ln|v-a|+\\
 & \frac{a^2+2a+7}{22}\ln\left(v^2+(a-1)v+a^2-a+1\right)+\\
 & \frac{8a^2-6a+12}{11\sqrt{3a^2-2a+3}}\tan^{-1}\frac{2v+a-1}{\sqrt{3a^2-2a+3}}+C\end{align}$$
So I wrote functions for the integrand and the integral and compared numerical integration with the analytical result and obtained similar results.

```
module M
   use ISO_FORTRAN_ENV, only: dp=>REAL64
   implicit none
   contains
      function f(x)
         real(dp) f, x, a
         real(dp), parameter :: c3 = 3
         real(dp), parameter :: c8 = sqrt(8.0_dp)
         a = 1/c3-c8/c3*sinh(1/c3*asinh(17/c8))
         f = (-a**2-2*a+4)/11*log(abs(x-a))+ &
            (a**2+2*a+7)/22*log(x**2+(a-1)*x+a**2-a+1)+ &
            (8*a**2-6*a+12)/11/sqrt(3*a**2-2*a+3)*atan((2*x+a-1)/sqrt(3*a**2-2*a+3))
      end function f
      function f16(x)
         real(dp) f16, x
         f16 = (x**2+1)/(x**3-x**2+x+1)
      end function f16
end module M
```

Comment: +1. I like your approach. Especially the way to only use one parameter $a$ through the calculations rather than the three I used. Will have to compare answers when I get back to my Mathematica PC.

Comment: Thanks @Ian Miller. How did you get your answer out so fast? +1 I think working in $\mathbb{Q}[x]\pmod{x^3-x^2+x+1}$ leads to more appealing solutions. It's a shame that Wolfram|Alpha doesn't produce solutions in that format.

Comment: Mostly I used Mathematica to help me with the fiddly nitty gritty work.