# How to do integral $\int\frac1{x^3+x+1}dx$?

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

I've been stuck by this integral. I only knew that roots of the cubic equation are complex.
Please help me with this. $$\int\frac{dx}{x^3+x+1}$$

Comment: by the way, there is a real root of the cubic equation

Comment: factorise I'd say, also note that this is already in the form of a depressed cubic

Comment: @HenryLee: I imagine the picture of "New Year Depressed Cubic" ;)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How calculate the indefinite integral $\int\frac{1}{x^3+x+1}dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1719288/how-calculate-the-indefinite-integral-int-frac1x3x1dx)

Comment: @philomath No, it is not my question.

Comment: @Naople How does it differ? Looks like the same integral to me.

Comment: @metamorphy yes haha, I find the name very fitting too for when trying to solve a cubic by hand

Answer (score 2):

Since $x^3+x+1=(x-a)((x-b)^2+c^2)$ [with](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+x%5E3%2Bx%2B1%3D0&dataset=)$$\begin{align}a&:=\sqrt[3]{\frac{\sqrt{93}-9}{18}}-\sqrt[3]{\frac{2/3}{\sqrt{93}-9}},\\b&:=\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{12(\sqrt{93}-9)}}-\sqrt[3]{\frac{\sqrt{93}-9}{144}},\\c&:=\sqrt{3}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{12(\sqrt{93}-9)}}+\sqrt[3]{\frac{\sqrt{93}-9}{144}}\right),\end{align}$$the integrand is as follows (double-check my partial fractions):$$\frac{1}{(x-a)((x-b)^2+c^2)}=\frac{1}{(b-a)^2+C^2}\left(\frac{1}{x-a}+\frac{(b-a)-(x-b)}{(x-b)^2+c^2}\right).$$So the most general antiderivative is$$\frac{1}{(b-a)^2+C^2}\left(\ln\frac{|x-a|}{\sqrt{(x-b)^2+c^2}}+\frac{b-a}{c}\arctan\frac{x-b}{c}\right)+C,$$where the locally constant function $C$ can have different values either side of $x=a$.

Comment: Thank you so much, now I can sleep tight. @J.G.

Comment: I would have used Bronstein's algorithm for this. The answer as returned by any sufficiently capable CAS is $\sum_{t:t^3+t+1=0}\frac{\log(x-t)}{3t^2+1}+K$.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel Do you mean Risch's algorithm? It's all I find when googling that name, but then algorithms often go by multiple names.

Comment: The name Bronstein is mentioned in SymPy's docs for `apart()`. Passing `full=True` implements this algorithm, an implicit PFD.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel Oh, [here](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/a8c2db2744b58b37414f490b9cb5b5db8d2f39d2/sympy/polys/partfrac.py#L31) & [here](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.49.3091&rep=rep1&type=pdf). Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

$x^3+x+1$ has one real and a pair of complex roots. The real root is $r= -0.6823$, given analytically by the Cardano’s formula. Decompose the integrand in terms of $r$
\begin{align}
\frac1{x^3+x+1}&= \frac1{(x-r)(x^2+rx-1/r)}
=\frac r{2r +3}\left(-\frac1{x-r}+\frac{x+2r}{x^2+rx-1/r}\right)
\end{align}

and then integrate to obtain
$$\int \frac{dx}{x^3+x+1}
=\frac r{2r +3}\left(-\ln\frac{x-r}{\sqrt{ x^2+rx-1/r}}
+\frac{ 3r \tan^{-1}\frac{2x+r}{\sqrt{1-3/r} } }{\sqrt{1-3/r}}\right)
$$
where $r^3=-r-1$ is recognized in above derivation.

Comment: thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

Decomposing in simple fractions,

$$\frac1{x^3+x+1}=\frac a{x-r}+\frac{bx+c}{x^2-2px+p^2+q^2}
\\=\frac a{x-r}+b\frac{x-p}{(x-p)^2+q^2}+\frac{bp+c}{(x-p)^2+q^2}.$$

The antiderivatives of the terms are

$$a\log(x-r)$$

$$\frac b2\log((x-p)^2+q^2)$$

and

$$\frac{bp+c}q\arctan\frac{x-p}q.$$

All coefficients are functions of the roots.

Comment: Crossed with J.G.

Comment: thank you @Yves Daoust

Answer (score 1):

My favored way with polynomials in denominator (for any degree with or without real roots)
$$\int\frac{dx}{x^3+x+1}=\int\frac{dx}{(x-a)(x-b)(x-c) }$$ where $(a,b,c)$ are the roots. Now, using partial fraction decomposition, the integrand is
$$\frac{1}{(a-b)
   (a-c) (x-a)}+\frac{1}{(b-a) (b-c) (x-b)}+\frac{1}{(c-a) (c-b) (x-c)}$$ So, the antiderivative is
$$\frac{\log(|x-a|)}{(a-b)
   (a-c) }+\frac{\log(|x-b|)}{(b-a) (b-c) }+\frac{\log(|x-c|)}{(c-a) (c-b) }$$ Now, computing the roots using the hyperbolic method for one real root
$$a=-\frac{2 }{\sqrt{3}}\sinh \left(\frac{1}{3} \sinh ^{-1}\left(\frac{3
   \sqrt{3}}{2}\right)\right)$$ Now, the sum of the roots is $0$ and their product is $-1$; moreover $b$ and $c$ are complex conjugate; then, they are "simple" to compute. By the end, recombining the second and third terms, you will end with an arctangent and a logarithm.

Comment: thank you so much